# Powershell and Regex: How to replace a INI name,value pair inside a named section?

Tags: regex, powershell, file-io

I'm playing with INI files in PowerShell v.2.0

I want to change a existing **name=value** pair inside a concrete section. By example: I want to set *color=Blue* for section *[Sky]* without change the same name,value pair inside *[Home]* Section.

I have the regex to get just the full section I want to change ('sky'):

```
[[ \t]*Sky[ \t]*\](?:\r?\n(?:[^[\r\n].*)?)*
```

I have also another expression that works, but only if Color is the first name,value pair of the section.

```
\[[ \t]*Sky[ \t]*\][.\s]*Color[ \t]*=[ \t]*(.*)
```

This is the sample ini file:

```
[Sky]
Size=Big
Color=white

[Home]
Color=Black
```

PS: This is the code that i'm using now to replace **all** instances of a name=value in the ini file and i want to update with the new expression **to replace only in a given section**

```
$Name=Color
$Value=Blue

$regmatch= $("^($Name\s*=\s*)(.*)")
$regreplace=$('${1}'+$Value)

if ((Get-Content $Path) -match $regmatch)
{
    (Get-Content -Path $Path) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $regmatch,$regreplace } | Set-Content $Path
}
```

---

**Edit:**

**@TheMadTechnician** solution it's perfect :)
Here the code in a Gist: [ReplaceIniValue_Sample2.ps1](https://gist.github.com/jatubio/5a61ea513cfa7ee93b03)

**@Matt** solution is another approach:
Here is the complete code:  [ReplaceIniValue_Sample1.ps1](https://gist.github.com/jatubio/428420b2aeca6a954bcc)

I'm looking for a solution based on regular expressions, but  **@mark z** proposal works perfectly and is a great example of API calls from Windows PowerShell. Here is the complete code with a few minor adjustments:  [ReplaceIniValue_Sample3.ps1](https://gist.github.com/jatubio/90cda6b32c0b19543a74)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I'd do: Read the whole file as a single string, then change your RegEx match so that it's a multiline match, then do a reverse lookup for [Sky] followed by capturing anything except '[' up to the option you want to change, capture everything on the other side of the equal sign in a second capture group, and replace as needed.

```
$Path="C:\Temp\prueba.ini"

@"
[Sky]
Size=Big
Color=White

[Home]
Color=Black
"@ | Set-content $Path

$Section="Sky"
$Name="Color"
$Value="Blue"

(Get-Content $Path) -join "`n" -replace "(?m)(?<=\[$Section\])([^\[]*$Name=)(.+?)$","`$1$Value" | Set-Content $Path
```

**Edit:** Almost forgot the obligatory RegEx101 link to explain my RegEx: https://regex101.com/r/uC0cC3/1

**Edit2:** Changed `-Raw` to `-ReadCount 0` for v2 compatibility.

**Edit3:** Ok, I evidently remembered incorrectly. I thought that `-ReadCount 0` worked the same as `-Raw` but it does not. Updated code to fix this. Now it joins the array of strings with new line characters basically turning it into a here-string and now the `-replace` works as expected.

Comment: Thanks @TheMadTechnician, i have tested yours and work on RegEx101 but not on poweshell :(

Gist of complete Code:
https://gist.github.com/jatubio/5a61ea513cfa7ee93b03

Comment: This was my fault, I incorrectly remembered how `-ReadCount 0` functioned and thought that it worked like `-Raw`. I have updated it and tested it. It works now with the addition of a `-join "`n"` statement. Also removed the `-ReadCount 0` since it was pointless.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps another solution is not use regex's at all and call the Windows API function `WritePrivateProfileString`. This is designed to edit ini files. However doing a PInvoke from PowerShell is a little tricky, you've got to compile some C# with Add-Type:

```
$source = @"

    using System.IO;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;

    public static class IniFile
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool WritePrivateProfileString(string lpAppName,
           string lpKeyName, string lpString, string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern uint GetPrivateProfileString(
           string lpAppName,
           string lpKeyName,
           string lpDefault,
           StringBuilder lpReturnedString,
           uint nSize,
           string lpFileName);

        public static void WriteValue(string filePath, string section, string key, string value)
        {
            string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(filePath);
            bool result = WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, value, fullPath);
        }

        public static string GetValue(string filePath, string section, string key, string defaultValue)
        {
            string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(filePath);
            var sb = new StringBuilder(500);
            GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, defaultValue, sb, (uint)sb.Capacity, fullPath);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source

function Set-IniValue {

   param (
       [string]$path,
       [string]$section,
       [string]$key,
       [string]$value
   )

   $fullPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($(Join-Path $pwd $path))
   [IniFile]::WriteValue($fullPath, $section, $key, $value)
}
```

However once you've go this, editing ini key value pairs is easy:

```
Set-IniValue -Path "test.ini" -Section Sky -Key Color -Value Blue
```

A couple notes on the usage. Setting a null value will delete the key. Setting a null key will delete the entire section.

Note there's a corresponding GetPrivateProfileString for reading values from an ini file. I've written the C# portion for that, I'll leave it as an exercise to reader to implement a PowerShell function for it.

Comment: Thanks @mike, I'm looking for a solution based on regular expressions, but yours works perfectly and is a great example of API calls from Windows PowerShell. You have my vote up :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok lets have a go at this.

```
@"

#This line have a white line after and before

[Sky]
Size=Big

Color=White

[Home]
Color=Black
#Last line
"@ | Set-content c:\temp\test.ini
```

Just using that code to create the file. Now lets make some changes.

```
$edits = (Get-Content c:\temp\test.ini) -join "`r`n" -split '\s(?=\[.+?\])' | ForEach-Object{
    If($_ -match '\[sky\]'){
        $_ -replace '(color=)\w+', '$1Blue'
    } Else {
        $_
    }
}

$edits | Set-Content c:\temp\test.ini
```

Read in the ini file using `Get-Content` and then `-join` it into one big string. We use `-split` to break up the file into its `[parts]`. We cycle each part looking for a section that contains `[sky]`. When we find the section were looking for just `replace` the word after "color" with blue.

There are some caveats with this approach but if the file is simple enough it should work. Have values in the code with [word] format will obviously cause the parsing to not work as intended but the result should still be the same.

**Spacing issue from testing**

I didn't realize it until Juan Antonio Tubío made me realize that subsequent passes of the code created *extra* whitespace. That was of how I broke up the file for parsing it. I fixed that by joining the array into one string before I outputted the file. Also to make subsequent tests easier to perform I made a function as well.

```
function Set-INIKey{
    param(
        [string]$path,
        [string]$section,
        [string]$key,
        [string]$value
    )

    $edits = (Get-Content $path) -join "`r`n" -split '\s(?=\[.+?\])' | ForEach-Object{
        If($_ -match "\[$section\]"){
            $_ -replace "($key=)\w+", "`$1$value"
        } Else {
            $_
        }
    }

    -join $edits | Set-Content $path
}
```

So when I used this over several tests then the extra whitespace no longer was present.

```
Set-INIKey "c:\temp\test.ini" "Sky" "Color" "Blue"
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt. Your code works, but put a new line before each section and i don't know how to fix it.

https://gist.github.com/jatubio/428420b2aeca6a954bcc

Comment: @JuanAntonioTubío oh.... ok  Should just be able to add a `trim` to that maybe. Updated the regex in the answer. Try again.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, now it's puttig white lines at the end of each section ;)

I have updated my gist code if you want to test him.

Comment: @JuanAntonioTubío those whitespaces exist in your code example. If you want to remove all white space that should not be to hard. Also you don't show how you are exporting my code to file. PowerShell would add a new line in some case to the end of the file. Added some trims

Comment: Here i put your code as I'm using to test: https://gist.github.com/jatubio/428420b2aeca6a954bcc .

Here, i put first version of ini.file, and results afer 3 runs: https://gist.github.com/jatubio/384d07e58207e7a9ac25/revisions .

As you can see, it's putting white lines every time it's read and write to file. Thanks for your Trim update, it works but i wan't change lines structure on target file.

Comment: @JuanAntonioTubío I think you should accept one of the other answers but try my update now. I think it was something `Set-Content` was doing with the pipe

Comment: Yes, i have tested your new code and keeps to add blank lines.

Comment: @JuanAntonioTubío sorry to hear that. Aside from adding a newline at the end my file looks just like the example I used in my answer. Glad TheMadTechnicians is working for you.

Comment: Have you tried to run your code several times? The first time allows to create the file and then comets that part of the code. Or, create the file by hand and remove that part of code.
        
In both cases, when you run it several times, repeating this code is what generates the extra blank lines.

Comment: @JuanAntonioTubío I see your point now. In case someone else finds this useful I will try and address it. Thanks.

Comment: Great!!

Matt, Thanks a lot for give me another solution

Answer (score 1):

```
 (Get-Content $path -raw) -join "`n" -replace "(?mi)(?<=\[$Section\])([^\[]*$Name=)(.*?)(\r?)$","`$1$Value`$3" | Set-Content $path -NoNewline
```

Just a slight improvement to TheMadTechnician's answer to allow preservation of Carriage Return characters if they exist (and to not add additional newline characters).