# script to remove section from a .ini

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line

I want a .bat file that can remove a section from a.ini file. So when runned i want a specific section removed. This value is known offcourse but the other content is variable and thus unknown. It also does not contain empty lines.

example test.ini start file

```
[above]
valuetestabove
[toberemoved]
valuetoberemoved
[below]
valuetestbelow
```

Wanted test.ini result

```
[above]
valuetestabove
[below]
valuetestbelow
```

I did try reading and writing every line with a start / end flag but it always deletes to much.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "start=[toberemoved]"
set "end=["
set "flag=0"

(for /f "delims=" %%i in (test.ini) do (
    if "%%i"=="!start!" ( 
        set "flag=1"
    )
    echo %%i | findstr "^!end!" >nul && (
        if "%%i" neq "!start!" (
            set "flag=0"
        )
    )
    if "!flag!"=="0" (
        echo %%i
    )
)) > newfile.txt
```

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your attempt into your question and thenwe may be able to fix it.

Comment: `echo %%i| findstr /b "!end!" >nul && (`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit/delete an entire section or just a line from an initialization file with script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980368/how-to-edit-delete-an-entire-section-or-just-a-line-from-an-initialization-file)

Answer (score 2):

Please see [Using Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35545602/2128947)
to allow this simplification which does not require `delayedexpansion`

Regardless, since `start` and `end` are not varied by the loop, `%start%`/`%end%` can be used in your original code (given the stray caret is removed)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q78080807.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

set "start=[toberemoved]"
set "end=["
set "flag=0"

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF "%%e"=="%start%" (SET "flag=") ELSE (
  ECHO %%e|FIND "%end%" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "flag=0"
 )
 IF DEFINED flag ECHO %%e
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

Note that `flag` is used as a Boolean - either it has a value (the value is irrelevant), or it is not defined.